Independence of two argmax
Problem: Suppose I have two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, also I have a measurable (for each $\theta$) function $f(X, \theta)$, where $\theta$ is a scalar parameter. I know that for each $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ $f(X_1)$ and $f(X_2)$ are independent. I want to show that
$$\text{argmax}_\theta f(X_1, \theta), \quad \text{argmax}_\theta f(X_2, \theta)$$
are independent.
Thoughts: I was trying to apply maximum theorem to treat argmax as a function of $f(X_1, \theta)$ and $f(X_2, \theta)$, however I do not understand how independence for each $\theta$ can be used to prove that argmax's are also independent.
